# Issue which appear only on laptops in Excel

Tags: excel

I am a student,

I have recently started using a laptop both at work in the classroom and in homework, and I almost always work with names, for some reason (I checked a few more laptops) the following happens:

I enter a function, work with F3 once, enter a multiplication or division action and then when I press F3 or For example,any other F from the F line it does not work, but if I get out of the Excel and return (like if I press the window key and return), suddenly I can work with the F line, I say in advance it probably does not have to do with the Fn key because the F on The computer itself is working normally, on a stationary computer, this case does not happen.
if anyone know the case, know what the solution is, please share.
thanks in advance,

Comment: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].*

Answer (score 0):

Your prefacing with the fn key not being the culprit does not leave much. Sounds like your function keys become disabled once some event is triggered in excel.

I want to reproduce the issue on other laptops. Correct me where I am wrong with the steps
1. Open Excel, and new sheet
2. click in a cell, enter a function example =2+2
3. move to new cell and press F3 (which is paste a name from paste name dialog box)
4. enter another formula
5. move to new cell and press F3 again (an no F keys work anymore at that point?)

Let me know if i have the steps correct. I tried a few laptops to test. I believe I can help you, just need to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: not quite... I will try to simplify my steps: 1. Open Excel, and new sheet. step 2. click in a cell, enter a function, for example =if(), in the window of the function (fx) I work with names (for instance cell B2 will now be 'fee' and hours throw names manager (=ctrl+f3)). step 3 in the logical test row I press on F3 so I have quick access to the names, and then I choose fee, times (*) hours. after click on * I cant use F3 again. is this now more clear?

Comment: Makes sense now. Testing now

Comment: I tested about 5 laptops. all the laptops with number pads worked fine. All the laptops that did not have a numberpad I had to do the opposite of what you think. When excel is open, the F keys were backwards. meaning to use a F3 in excel you have to hold down the Fn key. Which normally if you wanted to use the function, you would hold down the function key. If you are on a surface pro this is a nightmare as you need  3 hands or 1 very large hand to hold Fn + ctrl + F3

Comment: So just to recap: normally to use a Function key on a non numeric pad laptop, you hold down the function key. But if you are using Excel, MS decided on doing the opposite. With Excel, you have to hold down the function key to use F keys.  Let me know if that checks out on your end.

Comment: the thing is I do have full keyboard with numb digit pad and all and I have tried it on several laptop with numeric pad never the less the problem still there. and still I tried what you saying here. maybe we didn't understand each other perfectly throw hrere any chance we can chat via gmail?

Comment: Sure, chat is fine